# click doesn't load the page using chrome mobile simulator for webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, mobile, webdriver, simulator

trying to work with chrome mobile simulator (iPhone 6) , all the actions work on the web page except for click .It doesn't throw any exceptions but the click doesn't load the next page or submits the form .So no click actions are being performed even though the element is identified.

**website link for iphone 6** - www.sherwin-williams.com/painting-contractors

capabilities for iphone 6

```
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A4345d Safari/600.1.4";
deviceMetrics.put("width", 375);
deviceMetrics.put("height", 667);
deviceMetrics.put("pixelRatio", 2.0);
mobileEmulation.put("deviceMetrics", deviceMetrics);
mobileEmulation.put("userAgent", USER_AGENT );
options.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);                      
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

@FindBy(id = "off-canvas-header-trigger)
protected WebElement clicknavbar;

public MobilePage clicknavigation() {
        driver.click(clicknavbar, "Unable to click navigation bar");
        return this;

}

public boolean click(WebElement element, String errorMessage) {
    softAssert.setCause(null);

        boolean success = true;
        try {   


          element.click();
          }  catch (Exception  e) {
              throw e;
          }
         }
```

[html dom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK9bK.png)

Comment: it works with javascriptExecutioner but i dont want to use that approach as none of the clicks are taking place for the chrome simulator iphone 6

Comment: Your code trials for `Java click()` and the relevant `HTML DOM` please?

Comment: added the details you have asked for debanjan

Comment: `" missing @FindBy`

Comment: @findby is not the issue , i have it defined it properly in my script . for the code to work u can substitue it directly in the line its being used

Comment: is it the capabilities which is causing this ? i tried the same capabilities on a different website and still im unable to do any clicks .

Answer (score 0):

issue got resolved by updating chromedriver version to 2.35 from previous version which was 2.34